# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.HashMap

Tags: java, spring

I have below dependency added in pom.xml with `<jackson.version>2.7.4</jackson.version>`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

I checked few related questions but most of the solutions are either related with dependency missing or setter/getter issue. Here I am just putting values in a HashMap and returning it in response body but I am getting exception

```
@GetMapping("/json")
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, String> getValues() {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        map.put(UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
                String.valueOf(getRandomNumberBetween(0, 4)));
    }
    return map;
}
```

Whenever I call above URL I get below exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No converter found for return value of type: class java.util.HashMap
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:174)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:861)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at com.drools6spring.filter.SessionCookieFilter.doFilter(SessionCookieFilter.java:69)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:462)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:403)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:301)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:162)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:140)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Feb 7, 2018 9:37:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
```

Can anyone find out where I am going wrong.

Comment: could you try removing 'public' keyword from @ResponseBody and put it before function getValues()?

Comment: Just tried.. Not working that way also

Comment: If I am using String as return then it's working without any changes. Issue is with HashMap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying issue was with Maven Plugin in STS. Somehow it was not reflecting `pom.xml` declared dependencies inside project and also there were no errors in `pom.xml`. I re-installed the maven plugin and updated the project and it worked without any change in code.

Answer (score -2):

The problem should be you don't have a bean with the type is MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter, try to modify your ApplicationContext.xml as following:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven  />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="messageConverters">
        <list>
            <ref bean="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter">  
    <property name="messageConverters">  
        <list>  
               <ref bean="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter" />  
        </list>  
    </property>  
</bean>  

<bean id="mappingJacksonHttpMessageConverter"  
    class="org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter">  
     <property name = "supportedMediaTypes">  
          <list>  
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">  
             <constructor-arg index="0" value="text"/>  
             <constructor-arg index="1" value="plain"/>  
             <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8"/>  
            </bean>  
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">  
             <constructor-arg index="0" value="*"/>  
             <constructor-arg index="1" value="*"/>  
             <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8"/>  
            </bean>  
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">  
             <constructor-arg index="0" value="text"/>  
             <constructor-arg index="1" value="*"/>  
             <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8"/>  
            </bean>  
             <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">  
             <constructor-arg index="0" value="application"/>  
             <constructor-arg index="1" value="json"/>  
             <constructor-arg index="2" value="UTF-8"/>  
            </bean>  
          </list>  
    </property>  
</bean>
```

Contact me if it's still not working after you make this change.